# Automated Commercial Recorder

Tags: video, digital-recording

I'm working on a project and one part of the project needs me to create an application that needs to record commercials from the TV shows.

Basically people skip commercials, but in my case I need to record them. and for that Case I will need a trigger to let the recorder know that it is time to record!

This is one of the times that I searched Google alot couldn't figure out something!

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: You need to provide more information. How do you access the TV-show? Is it on television, on a DVD, in a video file? "Basically people skip commercials, but in my case I need to record them." Does the fact that people skip commercials have anything to do with the question? Please clarify the question so that we can help you! :)

Answer (score 1):

Mythtv could be of use to you.  It will automatically mark commercial in points and out points in a recording.  You could modify the their *transcode* shell script to cut the program and leave the commercials.